# How to update Guna Progress Bar in Winforms?

Tags: c#

I have question like below

```
private void UpdateProgressBar(int progress)
        {
            CheckerProgressBar.Maximum = 3250;
            CheckerProgressBar.Value = progress;

            progressBar1.Maximum = 3250;
            progressBar1.Value = progress;
        }
```

Checker - it is a Guna Progress Bar
progressBar1 - it is a default progressBar

This method is just for test.

Why guna bar does not update ?

I was looking for answer in google and was checking properties but everything looks ok...

EDIT

I found the solution. After every cycle gunaProgressBar requires to do
`CheckerProgressBar.Refresh();`

Comment: You may answer this yourself then here and mark it as solved. That helps other finding this having the same problem to spot the solution.